# I2C reception, false data reception in PIC

Tags: c, embedded, pic, i2c

I am trying to communicate with a device by using SMBUs. I use PIC18F26K83 and I can transmit a data. ( I guess.) I check I2CxCon0.B3 which is Master Data request bit and it gets set by the program. That means :

> Master state machine pauses until data is read/written to proceed
>   (SCL is output held low)

Also I check Transmit buffer empty bit and it gets cleared by the software.

So can I be sure that transmission was successful?

Then I send read address to slave and I check receive buffer full status bit. It gets 1 so I know that I received a data. However, all the data I get is 0. I ask for State of Charge and it cannot be zero. So my questions related to this one is:

1. When a transmission and receive processes be done, is there a chance still the transmission is corrupted? I mean unsuccessful.
2. Before enabling master start bit I load I2C count register. Do I also add to this register for the address buffer? For example I need to send data 0x0D to an address 0x16 and then receive a data. In this case I load count register 2 first, then after transmission for reading process I load 1. Is this correct way?
3. What can be the reason of false data reception? I guess hardware is correct because transmission and reception occurs. Also I2C configurations are again correct. So what can be the reason?

Here is the reception code: (A2 is the led I use for debugging. Nothing special)

```
 void SMBus_Data(){
      I2C2STAT1.B2 = 1;      // CLRBF=1, EMPTIES TRANSMIT BUFFER,i.e. TXBE=1
      I2C2ADB1     = 0x16;    //Address for smart battery
      I2C2TXB      = 0x0E;    //Relative SOC

      while (!I2C2STAT0.B7) {}  // BUS FREE BFRE=1
      I2C2CNT     = 1;          //BYTE COUNT REGISTER
      I2C2CON0.B6 = 1;          //RSEN=1;

       //******START**********
      I2C2CON0.B5 = 1;  //MASTER START BIT

      while(!I2C2CON0.B3) {}   //Master Data request
      while(!I2C2Stat1.B5){}   //Transmit Buffer empty status bit.
      I2C2ADB1    = (0x16 | 0x01);
      I2C2CNT     = 1;
      I2C2CON0.B5 = 1;         //MASTER START BIT
      I2C2CON0.B6 = 0;         //RSEN=1;
      while(!I2C2stat1.B0){}   //RXBF Receive Buffer Full Status Bit
      Data_10 = I2C2TXB ;
 }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format the code consistently. It's currently very hard to read and follow along.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Any better?

Comment: Easier to read, but no longer the same as before. Before you had some code inside some loops, now you don't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I deleted the unnecessary lines, they were the for the LED I use for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

`Data_10 = I2C2TXB ;` that should have been `Data_10 = I2C2RXB;`